# IMAC install of ubuntu, wireless mouse and keyboard not recognized

Tags: installation, wireless, keyboard, mouse

'm trying to install 11.10 on my mid 2011 imac but it doesn't seem to recognize my apple wireless keyboard or my magic mouse.

They're both bluetooth devices and they were recognized on windows 7 installation procedure on bootcamp.

So the problem is that i get to setup program of ubuntu 11.10 but i just can't do anything at all since i just can't control my imac.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a bluetooth device the magic mouse's code is 0000. Apple's wireless keyboard and magic mouse works great with debian testing!